# Can juju deploy the bundled openstack using multiple interfaces?

Tags: networking, juju, openstack

I have an underlaying openstack environment with admin, public, internal, tenant/tunnel, storage subnets defined. juju bundle charm deploys the openstack nodes as lxd containers using a single subnet - the admin network. This defeats the purpose of separating the traffic into public, internal, storage, etc.,

Can the juju charm lxds use multiple interfaces? If yes, could someone please share the bundle yaml file?

Thanks,
rick